# Insert string into quasiquote before it's interpolated (runtime quasiquote?)

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-quasiquotes

I'm trying to generate `Tree` for function that accepts case class value and returns value of case class parameter at given position. This is useful for extracting values of private parameters.

```
  import reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
  val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

  case class A(private val first: Int)

  case class B(first: Int, private val second: Int)

  def get(tpe: Type, position: Option[Int]): Tree = {
    val pos = s"${position.map(p => s"._${p + 1}").getOrElse("")}"
    tb.parse(s"(a: $tpe) => $tpe.unapply(a).get$pos")
  }

  println(tb.eval(get(typeOf[A], None)).asInstanceOf[(A) => Int](A(1)))

  println(tb.eval(get(typeOf[B], Some(1))).asInstanceOf[(B) => Int](B(1, 2)))
```

Also I added following dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
)
```

`position` is `None` when case class has only one parameter.

My solution is working, but how can I get rid of `tb.parse(s"...")` and **replace it with quasiquote** `q"..."`?

I tried that but it fails with:

```
Don't know how to unquote here
[error]     q"(a: $tpe) => $tpe.unapply(a).get$pos"
[error]                                        ^
```

As I understood I can not insert into quasiquote some string that's constructed at runtime and `q"..."` is parsed in compile time unlike `tb.parse`. **Am I right?**

Also is it safe to interpolate like that `s"(a: $tpe) => $tpe.unapply(a).get$pos"`? When using `q"..."` syntax quasiquote knows that `$tpe` is `Type` but string interpolation makes a string from it. I'm not sure that this will work always and in more complex and specific cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *not* right. Quasiquotes can't just interpolate normal strings, they must interpolate other pieces of AST. If you build up some fragments of AST yourself, then you can use them with `q`. Therefore, you can write this:

```
def getElem(tpe: Type, pos: Option[Int]): Tree = {
  // Make something like TermName("_N")
  val tupleAccess = pos.map("_" + _).map(TermName.apply)
  val tupleExpr = {
    val plain = q"${tpe.typeSymbol.companion}.unapply(a).get"
    // Build into $companion.unapply(a).get(._N)
    tupleAccess.foldLeft(plain)(Select.apply)
  }
  q"(a: $tpe) => $tupleExpr"
}
```

And voilà!

```
object A { object B { object C { case class D(private val x: Int, val y: String) } } }
val all = tb.eval(getElem(typeOf[A.B.C.D], None)).asInstanceOf[A.B.C.D => (Int, String)]
val int = tb.eval(getElem(typeOf[A.B.C.D], Some(1))).asInstanceOf[A.B.C.D => Int]
val str = tb.eval(getElem(typeOf[A.B.C.D], Some(2))).asInstanceOf[A.B.C.D => String]
val ds = {
  val D = A.B.C.D
  List(D(1, "one"), D(2, "two"), D(3, "three"))
}
ds.map(all) == List((1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three"))
ds.map(int) == List(1, 2, 3)
ds.map(str) == List("one", "two", "three")
```

Comment: I missed out `Select`. Is there any detailed documentation about that?